# Запись десятичных дробей в зависимости от языка приложения

Tags: java, android, multilanguage

Мне нужно, чтобы если в приложении стоит английский язык, во float разделителем была точка, а если русский, то запятая.

Есть ли условие, проверяющее текущий язык в приложении?

[image: клавиатура]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Можно так попробовать:

```
String currentSystemLang = Resources.getSystem().getConfiguration().locale.getLanguage();
String currentAppLang = Locale.getDefault().getLanguage();
```

[Вот туториал](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/how-to-get-current-default-language-of-android-device-programmatically/) для получения языка приложения и для получения языка [устройства](https://www.tutorialspoint.com/how-to-get-the-current-language-in-android-device). [Хороший туториал](https://medium.com/@hectorricardomendez/how-to-get-the-current-locale-in-android-fc12d8be6242) по работе с языками и [доки](https://developer.android.com/guide/topics/resources/multilingual-support)

Вообще [Qwertiy](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/178988/qwertiy) задал правильный вопрос. Поковырявшись немного я нашёл что у java есть такой класс как [DecimalFormatSymbols](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols.html) в котором спрятано довольно много полезностей. Вот например ниже строка позволяет получить разделительный символ, и он зависит от локали (Англ - точка, русский - запятая):

```
char separator = DecimalFormatSymbols.getInstance().getDecimalSeparator()
```

так же можно я так вижу поменять их на полностью свои символы:

```
DecimalFormatSymbols otherSymbols = new DecimalFormatSymbols(currentLocale);
otherSymbols.setDecimalSeparator(',');
otherSymbols.setGroupingSeparator('.'); 
DecimalFormat df = new DecimalFormat(formatString, otherSymbols);
```

[Вот доки](https://developer.android.com/reference/java/text/DecimalFormatSymbols) по этому направлению. Получение для определенной локали например выглядит так:

```
DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN)
```

Comment: То что надо, спасибо!

Comment: Это решает ещё и предыдущий вопрос

Comment: Эм.. А что, методов форматирования под нужный язык нет? И разве по умолчанию форматируется не в текущий язык?

Comment: @Qwertiy, спасибо, хороший вопрос) покопал немного в сторону того что вы спрашивали)

Comment: Интересно, но мне кажется легче проверить язык условием, так как у меня их всего 2

Comment: ну так тоже можно) просто есть и такая возможность тоже)

Comment: А оно реально должно делаться так сложно??? Вот вариант на шарпе: https://ideone.com/4G3991 - во-первых, он даже без параметров подстраивается под текущую культуру (и я всегда считал, что джава делает так же), во-вторых, даже для явного вывода мне достаточно создать один раз культуру на основе языка и просто передать её в ToString. И никаких ковыряний сепараторов и форматов. // cc @Art

Comment: ну вообще там можно и один раз вызывать это всё) просто если как-то хочется подменять на свои символы например то придется запариться

Comment: @Andrew, звать через `@` не забывай. А разобрался, я сначала невнимательно прочитал. Т. е. `DecimalFormat.getInstance(Locale.GERMAN)` достаточно, а туда надо в качестве параметра скормить `currentSystemLang` из первой строки ответа? Тогда да, в принципе компактно. Хотя у шарпа всё равно локоничнее и форматирование само по себе, а культура - сама по себе, поэтому их можно как угодно намешать.

Comment: @Qwertiy, завтыкал немного)) да там можно через один вызов, с шаром конечно не сравнить но тоже норм))

Comment: Кстати, а можно как-нибудь сделать, чтобы на клавиатуре тоже в зависимости от языка были разные разделители?

Comment: Сейчас добавлю скриншот к вопросу

Comment: Запятая есть, но она не активна, ни на русском языке, ни на английском (клавиатура numberDecimal|numberSigned)

Comment: @Art, это типа [такого](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12780125/soft-keyboard-with-comma-instead-of-dot-for-decimal-separator-in-android)

Comment: Хорошо, спасибо)) Сейчас попробую